# reference to println is ambiguous error

Tags: java

i have code a very basic program than when i do type System.out.println,  i get thes error: "reference to println is ambiguous" and the occured randomly it use to work and did not have a erroe but now it does and i cant figure this error occurs, so how do i fix this ,than you.

```
    package blue.light;
    //name is: slash
    import java.util.*;

    public class BlueLight {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name;
    int age;
    String a;
    String yes;
    String no;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double ans;





    System.out.println("hello, my name is Slash");
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("How old are you?");
    age = scan.nextInt();
    if(age < 18)
            {
                System.out.println("ur young af");
            }
    else if (age == 21)
    {
        System.out.println("Shots, shots, shots");

    }
    else if (age == 69)
    {
        System.out.println("ohhh yea");
    }
    System.out.println("you to calculate any thing?");
    a = scan.nextLine();
    if(a==("yes")){
        System.out.println("What would u like to do?(multiply,or add)");     
        a = scan.nextLine();
                    if(a == "add"){
            System.out.println("Enter number 1");
            num1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter number 2");
            num2 = scan.nextDouble();
                    ans = num1+num2;

        }


    }

}
    }
```

Comment: it works in eclipse but not in netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `nextInt()` doesn't consume the new line after the age (so your `nextLine` is then empty). You compare `Object` values with a call to `.equals()` because `==` tests reference identity (and with a `String` I'd use [`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-)). Finally, I'd declare the variables with minimum visibility in Java; as close to their first use as possible. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("hello, my name is Slash");
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("How old are you?");
    int age = scan.nextInt();
    if (age < 18) {
        System.out.println("ur young af");
    } else if (age == 21) {
        System.out.println("Shots, shots, shots");
    } else if (age == 69) {
        System.out.println("ohhh yea");
    }
    System.out.println("you to calculate any thing?");
    scan.nextLine(); // <-- nextInt leaves a trailing new line.
    String a = scan.nextLine();
    if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) { // <-- compare string for equality in
                                        // Java
        System.out.println("What would u like to do?(multiply,or add)");
        a = scan.nextLine();
        if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {// <-- compare string for equality
                                        // in Java
            System.out.println("Enter number 1");
            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter number 2");
            double num2 = scan.nextDouble();
            double ans = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println(ans); // <-- display answer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after that it still isnt fixed

Comment: In what way is it not fixed? Did you redefine `System`?

Comment: i believe so  and the error still comes uo for the S.O.P                                 error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - reference to println is ambiguous
  both method println(java.lang.String) in java.io.PrintStream and method println(Object) in java.io.PrintStream match
 at blue.light.BlueLight.main(BlueLight.java:19)

Comment: What is line 19 of `BlueLight.java`?

Comment: it is:     System.out.println("hello, my name is Slash");

Comment: Are you sure? Clean your project.

Comment: how so? what do i do?

Comment: From the [NetBeans IDE Java Quick Start Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html), *To build your application: Choose Run > Clean and Build Project.*